# How do i call a SQL scalar function specified in a strongly typed dataset in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, dataset, user-defined-functions

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and have created a datasource using the IDE.  Using the wizard, I included a few tables, views and a function.  However, the function is not showing up in intellisense.

How do I call the scalar function in the strongly typed dataset?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the typed dataset you end up with a file call `MyDataSet.Designer.cs`.  Look in there and you'll find two classes `MyDataSet` and `QueriesTableAdapter`.  `QueriesTableAdapter` will have a method corresponding to your function.